# How to load a CSV txt file into R correctly

Tags: r, csv, read.csv

I'm very new to R, and having some simple trouble. I thought I understood the read.table() function, but apparently not. I'm trying to load "http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/users/nolan/data/bikeshare.txt" into RStudio, and for whatever reason, it only displays the text file again. My command was:

```
read.table("http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/users/nolan/data/bikeshare.txt",
           sep=",", 
           header=True)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to assign it to a variable `x <- read.table(...)`, otherwise it will just print to the console.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry if it was a dumb question, this is my first solo assignment for a class. I'm trying to get comfortable with everything still. Thanks again.

Comment: Booleans are all-caps in R, i.e. `TRUE`. You might as well use `read.csv` here, though: `bike <- read.csv('https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/users/nolan/data/bikeshare.txt', stringsAsFactors = TRUE)` The last parameter will keep the dates as character strings instead of factors, though really `as.Date` can handle either.

Comment: This type of text file is called a CSV file (Comma-Separated Value), and `read.csv` is an alias to `read.table()`, just with the settings you'd need to read a CSV.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

### Code Example:

```
URL <- "http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/users/nolan/data/bikeshare.txt"
bikeshare <- read.table(URL, sep=",", header=TRUE)
head(bikeshare)
```

### Example Output:

```
> URL <- "http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/users/nolan/data/bikeshare.txt"
> bikeshare <- read.table(URL, sep=",", header=TRUE)
> head(bikeshare)
  instant     dteday season yr mnth hr holiday weekday workingday weathersit temp  atemp  hum windspeed casual registered cnt
1       1 2011-01-01      1  0    1  0       0       6          0          1 0.24 0.2879 0.81    0.0000      3         13  16
2       2 2011-01-01      1  0    1  1       0       6          0          1 0.22 0.2727 0.80    0.0000      8         32  40
3       3 2011-01-01      1  0    1  2       0       6          0          1 0.22 0.2727 0.80    0.0000      5         27  32
4       4 2011-01-01      1  0    1  3       0       6          0          1 0.24 0.2879 0.75    0.0000      3         10  13
5       5 2011-01-01      1  0    1  4       0       6          0          1 0.24 0.2879 0.75    0.0000      0          1   1
6       6 2011-01-01      1  0    1  5       0       6          0          2 0.24 0.2576 0.75    0.0896      0          1   1
```

### Recommended Reading

If you want to learn more about R, I'd recommend the following free resources.

- [Quick R Web Site](https://www.statmethods.net/)
- [R for Data Science - Hadley Wickham](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/)
- [Advanced R - Hadley Wickham](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/)